# sap.m.InputBase - selectText on iOS devices

Tags: sapui5

I noticed that the `selectText` method of `sap.m.InputBase` doesn't work on iOS devices (mobile safari).

How can I handle it? Should I use the JavaScript `HTMLInputElement.setSelectionRange()` method?
There is no "SAP UI5" standard way?

Comment: In place of `InputBase#selectText`, The DOM API `HTMLInputElement.select()` might be more suitable since `.select()` supports selecting the whole text and even input fields with `type="Number"`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58978363/5846045

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use the `selectText` function in iOS safari, the input needs to be on focus and the keyboard has to be opened.
The function has to be used with 2 parameters – start and end indexes.
Internally, we use `setSelectionRange()`.

In the documentation, it says:
Selects the text within the input field between the specified start and end positions. Only supported for input control's type of Text, Url, Tel and Password.